# XAML - Center alignment of textblock after rotation

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, textblock, xaml-designer

I have a stackpanel with textblock and image. I need to align the textblock to center with rotation(90 degree).Like this,

[image]

But, after rotate the textblock i am always getting result like this,

[image]

this is the XAML code i am using,

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="120" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/mail.jpg"/>
        <TextBlock Text="send mail" FontSize="15" Margin="25,0,0,0" >
            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
```

how can i align my textblock to center..?

Answer (score 8):

Setting the VerticalAlignment of the TextBlock to 'Center' and Rotating around the TextBlocks center point by setting RenderTransformOrigin should help.

```
<TextBlock Text="xyz" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="25,0,0,0">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Additionally try to set RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" to rotate your element around it's center. I also updated my answer.

Comment: Used the RenderTransformOrigin on my solution worked like a charm. Thank you!